# Happens-before when synchronized method exits

Tags: java, multithreading

The Oracle [lesson on concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) states:

> Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object.

This seems to be trivially true, since "subsequent" implies that it happens after the synchronized method exits. This statement seems to be true of un-synchronized methods as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that "subsequent" has nothing to do with the passage of time; it has to do only with where the method invocations appear in the *synchronization order*. This is the essential difference between *linearizability* (strict ordering by wall-clock time, not guaranteed by the Java Memory Model) and *sequential consistency* ("consistent with some ordering", guaranteed for data race-free programs). The phrase "happens before" is also deceptive because it doesn't imply time ordering, either.

For unsynchronized methods there is simply no ordering because their invocations don't appear in the synchronization order.

As you very nicely summarize in the comments:

> Every execution has some order on synchronization actions which may or may not be the same as the "actual" execution order. However, this synchronization order is consistent with program order of individual threads. Moreover, if exiting a synchronized method occurs earlier in the synchronization order than entering a synchronized method on the same object, then all reads in the entered method see writes in the exited method.

Comment: What is the difference between synchronization order and the happens-before relation?

Comment: Happens-before encompasses more actions than the sync order because happens-before covers the program order of non-sync actions as well.

Comment: Watch out not to assume that "happens before" has anything to do with the passage of time, because it doesn't. It is only about the causality ordering.

Comment: If A comes before B in the synchronization order, does A happen before B? If so, it still seems like the claim is trivially true.

Comment: `A synchronizes-with B` implies `A happens-before B`. Non-synchronized methods do not appear in the sync order, therefore they don't get the ordering unless called on the same thread (ordering by program order).

Comment: However, `A precedes-on-sync-order B` does not imply `A synchronizes-with B`. Only actions involving the same lock object get that, and then only pairs of actions where A is a release action and B is an acquire action.

Comment: I think I understand now. Every execution has some order on synchronization actions which may or may not be the same as the "actual" execution order. However, this synchronization order is consistent with program order of individual threads. Moreover, if exiting a synchronized method occurs earlier in the synchronization order than entering a synchronized method on the same object, then all reads in the entered method see writes in the exited method.

Comment: By the way, your answer was very helpful, but it might be useful for others to incorporate some of the comments in your answer.

Comment: Also, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13247614/3778892, the Java memory model does not guarantee sequential consistency.

Comment: The succinct phrase that describes the guarantees is "sequential consistency for datarace-free programs."

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a non-volatile field `f` that holds value *v*, and suppose that thread A updates field `f` with value *w*, and suppose that thread B subsequently reads field `f`.

You might be surprised to learn that there is *not* any happens before relationship between the update and the read.  The Java Language Specification (JLS) allows thread B to get *v* when it reads the field even though, according to the wall clock, the read happened subsequent to the update.

Everything that happens within one thread is required to happen in *program order*.  If the code executed by thread A looks like it updates some field, and then later reads the field, then the  JLS requires that the read get the value that was written (i.e., the write "happens before" the read).

There is no such requirement when the read and the write happen in different threads.  In general, events that happen in one thread are independent of events that happen in another thread *except* in certain special cases.  Entering and leaving `synchronized` blocks are one of those special cases.

When the JLS says that leaving a synchronized block "happens before" a subsequent entry into a block synchronized on the same object, it means that the happens before relationship is true *even when the events happen in different threads.*

Comment: This is as true of volatile fields as of non-volatile because time simply doesn't matter in JMM, or in sequential consistency in general.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Time matters because time _happens_.  Events actually happen in some time-order.  Sometimes we can reason about the order, sometimes not.  If thread B in my example reads field `f` and gets value _w_, that _proves_ that thread A wrote the field before thread B read it.  What I'm trying to tell the OP is that "x happens before y" does not mean that x always will happen before y.  It only means that if you can prove that x _actually did_ happen before y, then you are allowed to use that information to make inferences about the time ordering of other, related events.

Comment: "events actually happen in some time-order"---even that's not true. There may be no actual event corresponding to a volatile write, as long as the rules of the specification are observed. Observing a value doesn't prove anything about the physical events on the machine. A value can be observed speculatively, for example, before it's written. You are definitely _not_ allowed to make inferences about time ordering because that would imply _linearizability_, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: As a specific example, consider this. Initially a volatile variable `x == 0`. Thread _a_ at some point writes 1 to `x`. At time `t == 1`, thread _b_ observes `x == 1`. At time `t  == 2`, thread _c_ observes `x == 0`. Is this a violation of the JMM?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I see no problem.  But let me go further:  Let thread _a_ sets _non_ volatile `y=1` _before_ setting `x=1`, and threads _b_ and _c_ examine `y` _after_ examining `x`.  My understanding is that the JLS requires thread _b_ to see `y==1` if it previously has seen `x==1`, but thread _c_ could see either `y==0` or `y==1` if it previously has seen `x==0`.  Thread _b_ can complete the chain of "happens before" inferences because it can see that the volatile write happened.  Thread _c_ can't complete the chain because news of the volatile write has not yet reached it.

Comment: All true and no reasoning by time, but by program order.