# Is it guaranteed that volatile field would be properly initialized

Tags: java, volatile, java.util.concurrent, java-memory-model

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

Are the same guarantees held for the `volatile` field?
What if the `y` field in the following example would be `volatile` could we observe `0`?

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
final int x;
int y; 
static FinalFieldExample f;

public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3; 
    y = 4; 
} 

static void writer() {
    f = new FinalFieldExample();
} 

static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
        int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
        int j = f.y;  // could see 0
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: The semantics are similar but not the same.  `volatile` guarantees that all actions (reads and writes) that happen before the write to the `volatile` are visible.  `final` guarantees that only that particular field (and any object the field refers to) is visible.  `final` is called out explicitly to NOT have a transitive relationship with all other actions on a thread.  (So, previous reads and writes on a thread are unaffected by a `final` field.)

Comment: @mark no: `final` means the value (which can be a reference) is assigned exactly *once*, and assignment happens during object initialization - it may never be reassigned. `final` has nothing to do with visibility.

Comment: You are 100% wrong about that.  Read the link the OP provided.  I'd also recommend Brian Geotz's book, Java Concurrency in Practice.  This is well known semantics for Java's `final` keyword.

Comment: `final` is for initialization and `volatile` is about updating the variable at the same.

Comment: @markspace can you provide a JCIP citation?

Comment: *"...Let o be an object, and c be a constructor for o in which a final field f is written. A freeze action on final field f of o takes place when c exits...Given a write w, a freeze f, an action a (that is not a read of a final field), a read r1 of the final field frozen by f, and a read r2 such that hb(w, f), hb(f, a), mc(a, r1), and dereferences(r1, r2), then when determining which values can be seen by r2, we consider hb(w, r2). (This happens-before ordering does not transitively close with other happens-before orderings.)"*

Comment: Note that this freeze-action is distinct from a synchronizes-with but still creates a happens-before relationship.  (And Brian Goetz's book is a much easier read that trying to puzzle out the spec.)

Comment: @mark I don't see the word "visibility" anywhere in that text. `final` doesn't need `volatile` because its value never changes, but that has nothing to do with visibility. Are you still sure "I'm 100% wrong"?

Comment: Er, I don't think the OP is asking if the field needs to be both `volatile` and `final`.  It's one or the other.  And *happens-before* means "visible" in the JLS.  You need to read that entire chapter for it to make sense: JLS section 17.4.5. Happens-before Order *"Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second."*  I'm not really interested in spoon feeding this to you.  Please make an effort on your own, or at least ask a question here that someone can answer. @Bohemian

Comment: OP: look at user17206833's answer below.  It appears to (very cogently) explain that `y` can be 0 even if `volatile`.  Something I was not aware of, and seems to be a subtle point in the Java memory model.

Comment: as to the other question that you posted, I will provide the same comment. This is a "data race", yes, zero is such a possibility. The guarantees for `final` in the spec, are for _all_ fields, your example violates that. But it is very tricky, I agree. Although I really like these things, I sometimes get them wrong too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to see `0` when

```java
class FinalFieldExample { 
  final int x;
  volatile int y;
  static FinalFieldExample f;
  ...
}
```

The short explanation:

- `writer()` thread publishes `f = new FinalFieldExample()` object via a data race
- because of this data race, `reader()` thread is allowed see `f = new FinalFieldExample()` object as semi-initialized.
  In particular, `reader()` thread can see a value of `y` that was before `y = 4;` — i.e. initial value `0`.

More detailed explanations are [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-volatiles-are-finals).

You can reproduce this behavior on ARM64 with [this jcstress test](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/0.16/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_13_VolatileVsFinal.java).

Comment: you need to look closely at the jcstress example + OP's example. There _is_ a `final` in OPs example, which, in the current implementations (I've looked at 8 to 17), makes a big difference: zero is not possible. But JLS allows it.

Answer (score 4):

I think reading 0 is possible.

The spec [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> A write to a volatile variable `v` synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of `v` by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

In our case, we have a write and a read of the same variable, but there is nothing that ensures the read to be subsequent. In particular, the write and read occur in different threads that are not related by any other synchronization action.

That is, it is possible that the read will occur before the write in synchronization order.

This may sound surprising given that the writing thread writes `f` after `y`, and the reading thread reads `y` only if it detects `f` has been written. But since the write and read to `f` are not synchronized, the following [quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) applies:

> More specifically, if two actions share a happens-before relationship, they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order to any code with which they do not share a happens-before relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

The [explanatory notes to example 17.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) also reaffirm that the runtime is permitted to reorder these writes:

> If some execution exhibited this behavior, then we would know that instruction 4 came before instruction 1, which came before instruction 2, which came before instruction 3, which came before instruction 4. This is, on the face of it, absurd.
>
> However, compilers are allowed to reorder the instructions in either thread, when this does not affect the execution of that thread in isolation.

In our case, the behavior of the writing thread, in isolation, is not affected by reordering the writes to `f` and `y`.

Comment: it is possible according to the `JLS`, since this is a data race, yes. It is impossible in the current implementation of the JVM (strictly taking into account OPs example), because it takes _at least_ one final field for the proper barriers to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `0` is possible when `x` is volatile, because there is no guarantee that the write `x = 3` in the `writer()` thread **always** [*happens-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) the read `local_f.x` in the `reader()` thread.

```java
class FinalFieldExample { 
  volatile int x;
  static FinalFieldExample f;

  public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3;
  }

  static void writer() {
    f = new FinalFieldExample();
  }

  static void reader() {
    var local_f = f;
    if (local_f != null) {
        int i = local_f.x;  // could see 0
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, even though `x` is `volatile` (which means that all reads and writes to `x` happen in a global order), nothing prevents the read `local_f.x` in the `reader()` thread from happening before the write `x = 3` in the `writer()` thread.
`local_f.x` in these case will return `0` (the [default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) for `int`, which works like an initial write).

The problem is that after the `reader()` thread reads `f`, there is no guarantee (i.e. no *happens-before* relation) that it sees the inner state on `f` correctly: i.e. it may not see the write `x = 3` into the inner field `f.x` made by the `writer()` thread in `FinalFieldExample` constructor.

You can create this *happens-before* relation by:

- either making `f` `volatile` (`x` can be made non-volatile)

  ```java
  class FinalFieldExample { 
    int x;
    static volatile FinalFieldExample f;
    ...
  }
  ```

  [From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

  > A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.
- or making `x` `final` instead of `volatile`

  ```java
  class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    static FinalFieldExample f;
    ...
  }
  ```

  [From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

  > An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My answer below looks like it's wrong.  `volatile` only requires that all reads and writes (and other "actions") have completed when the write is made, but subsequent writes can still be reordered to occur before the write to the `volatile`.  Thus it is possible to see `f` before the write to `y` has occurred.

Which is really weird, but here we are.

user17206833's answer above mine appears to be correct and contains a link to a very useful resource, I suggest you check it out.

---

**Wrong stuff (I'm leaving it up because it illustrate a common misconception):**

OP I think I misread your question:

*"What if the y field in the following example would be volatile could we observe 0?"*

If `y` is volatile, then no you cannot observe a 0.

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
  final int x;
  volatile int y;
```

If this is what you mean, then the write to `y` followed by a read of `y` must create a *happens-before* edge for the read.  [The JLS says:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) *"A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field."* and never qualifies that statement requiring a read of a reference of some type.  The fact that `f` is neither `volatile` nor `final` should make no difference.

Comment: How do you know the read "follows" the write? Are you assuming the Java Memory Model to be sequentially consistent? [It's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247539/jmm-sequential-consistency).

Comment: Correct. That why I am asking how you know this condition to be true?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The OP is asking if a read of `y` will result in a 4 or a 0, after `y` is written with a 4 in the ctor when `y` is declared `volatile` (I think we and the OP all agree that if `y` is not `volatile` then of course it could be 0).  Surely this read of y will be 4 after the write of 4 in the ctor.  (The read only happens if `f` has been assigned (the OP checks for `null`) and `f` can only be assigned if the ctor has run.  I don't see any other possible code path.)

Comment: So you're assuming that operations done in different threads execute one after the other, in some particular order. That is known as sequential consistency. The problem is that the Java Memory Model guarantees sequential consistency only for correctly synchronized code, but the OP's code is not correctly synchronized, since `f` is shared through a data race. Incorrectly synchronized code need not be sequentially consistent, i.e. different threads may have a different perspective and  perceive memory updates in a different order from each other.

Comment: user17206833's answer above is starting to convince me I'm wrong.  I find it a little shocking that a write (of any field) could be reordered before a write to a `volatile` but it appears the JLS does allow this.  I'm going to poke at this a bit more and see what I get.  (Also user17208506's answer below mine appears to be correct and deserves an up-vote.)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, `volatile` and initialization are unrelated concepts: A field's initialization guarantees are unaffected by it being `volatile` or not.

Unless `this` "escapes" from within the constructor (which is not the case here), the constructor is guaranteed to have completed execution *before* any other process can access the instance's fields/methods, so `y` must be initialized in `reader()` if `f != null`, ie

```
int j = f.y;  // will always see 4
```

See [JLS `volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

Comment: Does it mean I could observe `f.y` as 0? (when `y` is volatile)

Comment: @Hlib It is very unlikely and I don't think so. Because in your example, if you say that you could see `0`, that means even both methods `writer()` and `reader()` are synchronized, it does not guarantee that the field has been initialized; isn't that break the whole language itself.

Comment: @Hlib No. For `f` to be not null, the initialization of the instance must have completed: The assignment of the instance to the variable `f` happens *after* instance initialization. See edits to answer.

Comment: @Darkman It is not possible to see `0` at the line in question.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, that's what I thought. It's all because of one line: `if(f != null)`.

Comment: In reasoning "For f to be not null, the initialization of the instance must have completed" you are assuming sequential consistency, but the Java Memory Model guarantees sequential consistency only for correctly synchronized code, which this code is not, since `f` is shared through a data race.

Comment: you need to look at the JLS guarantees, and in OPs example, there is a data race, zero is possible. This answer is wrong.