# Does the java memory model prevent interleaving writes from different threads between volatile variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling, volatile, java-memory-model

I was reading an interesting article about [the memory barriers and their role in JVM concurrency](https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency/), and the example implementation of Dekker's algorithm took my attention

```
     volatile boolean intentFirst = false;
     volatile boolean intentSecond = false;
     volatile int turn = 0;


     // code run by first thread    // code run by second thread

 1    intentFirst = true;           intentSecond = true;
 2
 3    while (intentSecond) {        while (intentFirst) {     // volatile read
 4      if (turn != 0) {               if (turn != 1) {       // volatile read
 5        intentFirst = false;               intentSecond = false;
 6        while (turn != 0) {}               while (turn != 1) {}
 7        intentFirst = true;                intentSecond = true;
 8      }                              }
 9    }                             }
10    criticalSection();            criticalSection();
11
12    turn = 1;                     turn = 0;                 // volatile write
13    intentFirst = false;          intentSecond = false;     // volatile write
```

The article mentions that since volatiles are sequentially consistent, the critical section is bound to be executed by one thread, which checks out with the happens-before guarantee. However, does that still hold if the two threads continue to execute the same logic in a loop? My understating is that the underlying OS scheduler may decide to pause the second thread in subsequent execution just before line 7 is executed and leave the first thread hit the critical section, and at the same moment, the OS resume the second thread and hit the critical section simultaneously. Is my understanding correct, and this example is given with the idea that this code is executed only once? If so, I'd assume that the answer to my question is "no" since volatiles are used only for memory visibility guarantees.

Comment: The compiler ensures that the compiled code on the platform - in this case the JVM - makes certain guarantees in terms of reordering of statements surrounding a volatile read/write, and about visibility between threads. On most platforms that have a JVM implementation, this can be done without the involvement of the operating system, and no scheduling is involved. On its own, a memory barrier is not an exclusion mechanism, you need something like Dekker's algorithm for that, or a simpler one if your hardware supports [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operations.

Comment: The implementation above is Dekker's algorithm using three volatiles. Still, my mind keeps thinking of how the java threads (which AFAIK are OS managed threads) could be paused (due to exhausting their quantum or due to other higher-priority threads being scheduled), so these visibility guarantees do not seem to be enough to hold the critical section safe if the two threads execute the logic above in a loop. I think I'm on the same page with what you said, with the exception that I'm not sure I understood what you meant by no scheduling is involved when JVM is put in the mix? @Emmef

Comment: `The article mentions that since volatiles are sequentially consistent,` Careful, this is not strictly true.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638262/is-it-guaranteed-that-volatile-field-would-be-properly-initialized

Comment: @George what I meant is that the underlying implementation that the JVM uses to make volatiles behave according to its specifications,  are handled on the compiler and instruction level: they do not at all involve the operating system. And thus, volatile behaviour has nothing to do with scheduling. (I do not know of a platform with a supported JVM that needs to use operating system features to implement volatiles)

Comment: I don't see any way for Dekker's algorithm above to be wrong, but just saying "volatile is sequentially consistent" is overbroad and needs some qualification (see my comment above).  As Emmef points out below, this algorithm is pretty inefficient and there are much better options in Java.

Comment: @markspace, the sequentially consistent statement is my blunt simplified interpretation of the beautiful article (I don't want to put incorrect statements). The main purpose was to centre the discussion around the above algorithm and whether it holds true in all cases in its current implementation. My imagination says it was used only for descriptive purposes but isn't actually correct when used in a real multi-threaded environment. At the same time, it may be a flaw in my understanding leading me to believe it's incorrect, in which case I'd like to fix my gaps.

Comment: @markspace , many thanks for the additional stack; it was definitely an interesting and tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understating is that the underlying OS scheduler may decide to
> pause the second thread in subsequent execution just before line 7 is
> executed and leave the first thread hit the critical section, and at
> the same moment, the OS resume the second thread and hit the critical
> section simultaneously.

This will not happen. If the second thread gets suspended and the first thread
is in the critical section, the `intentFirst` is still true since this is only set to false after the first thread leaves the critical section. So if the second thread wakes up, the `intendSecond` is set to true, but the second thread will be stuck in the `while(intendedFirst)` loop and will delay entering the critical section till the first thread has excited.

IMHO the most interesting part of Dekkers algorithm with respect to happens-before is here:

```
intentSecond=true; // volatile write
while(intendFirst) // volatile read
```

Modern processors have store buffers and this could lead to older stores being reordered with newer loads to a different address. That is why a [StoreLoad] is needed between the earlier store and the later load to ensure that they are sequentially consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler ensures that the compiled code on the platform - in this case the JVM - makes certain guarantees for volatile variables, in terms of [reordering of statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) (on many levels) and about visibility between threads. On most platforms that have a JVM implementation, this can be done without the involvement of the operating system, and no scheduling is involved.

Guarantees about reordering and memory barriers are themselves no exclusion mechanism, needed to enter a critical section. These can be implemented in many different ways, for example by Dekker's algorithm. Dekker's algorithm is a so-called *busy* algorithm, that needs the CPU to work for as long as it is not allowed into the critical section. On modern hardware, simpler algorithms are possible that can use [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operations, for example

```
// declare an atomic boolean (package java.util.concurrent.atomic)
AtomicBoolean busyFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

// the part with the critical section, same for all threads
while (!busyFlag.compareAndSet(false, true)) { /* busy wait */ }
try {
    criticalSection();
}
finally {
    busyFlag.set(false);
}
```

In this case, `[compareAndSet][3]` ensures that the flag is *atomically set* to true if and only if it is false, and returns true when that happens.

However, just like the Dekker algorithm, this is still a busy mechanism that can cost you a lot of CPU if you are unlucky. A `synchronized` section or a [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) will ask the operating system to suspend the current thread when the lock cannot be obtained. But that has nothing to do with `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown @Emmef. Your points are doubling down on my understanding that the volatile usage in the snippet in the question is not enough to guarantee correctness if called multiple times. Meaning that taking turns is not guaranteed for subsequent runs, and both threads could hit the critical section simultaneously. This is if we do not look at it in isolation (being called only once). Is this correct, or is my brain playing tricks with me making me see what I want to see?

Comment: Please ignore the comment above. Indeed my late night brain was making incorrect jumps in the logic. You're absolutely correct.

Comment: I wish I could give an upvote to your answer due to the plethora of useful information, all giving the right pointers to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `synchronized` and `ReentrantLock`’s `lock()` method also use `cas`, even in a loop where feasible. The difference is that the implementation has useful heuristics to decide when to switch from polling in a loop to enqueuing and suspending the current thread.